# How to use new line if character exceed to 25

Tags: vb.net

labelsample.text = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789

```
If samplelabel.textlength = 25 then
   'How to move it to nextline?
```

Output should be like this:

```
  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx    
  z123456789
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MOD operator to decide when to insert a carriage return.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim sampleText As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789"
        For i As Integer = 1 To sampleText.Length
            sb.Append(sampleText(i - 1))
            If i Mod 25 = 0 Then
                sb.AppendLine()
            End If
        Next
        Label1.Text = sb.ToString
    End Sub
End Class
```